# Problems with running Selenium exported tests in Visual Studio

Tags: selenium, testing

I am having troubles with running tests (exported from Selenium IDE) inside Visual Studio 2013.

When I use Selenium IDE, all tests pass without any problems.

After I export them as *.cs* files, Visual Studio discovers them without any troubles but can not get them to work past the base URL. In other words, it loads the page, but **nothing happens**. After a while, it goes in timeout and quits browser.

Is there some part of code I need to edit in order to get it to work?

I added commands to 1. wait for, 2. verify and 3. **click** on button/element/radio/link but it does not help.

I hope you can help me to somehow resolve this problem. Regards!

The code (without base URL):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Black
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    private string baseURL;
    private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseURL = "https://something.com/";
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheBlackTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "something");
        for (int second = 0; ; second++)
        {
            if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
            try
            {
                if (IsElementPresent(By.Id("something"))) break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        for (int second = 0; ; second++)
        {
            if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
            try
            {
                if (IsElementPresent(By.Id("something"))) break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        try
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.Id("something")));
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
        }
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#something > div.ng-binding")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#something > div.ng-binding")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("something")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("something")).Click();
    }
    private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool IsAlertPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText()
    {
        try
        {
            IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            string alertText = alert.Text;
            if (acceptNextAlert)
            {
                alert.Accept();
            }
            else
            {
                alert.Dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        }
        finally
        {
            acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And can you show us what you do?

Comment: I record test using Selenium IDE for Fire Fox and export it as .cs file.
 Later after importing it in Visual Studio 2013, it only loads base URL and does nothing after that. 

How can i paste the code here?